# Integrating twitter pull request with another application

Tags: ruby, api, web-applications, twitter

i'm an absolute newbie to webapps, so please forgive if my question is quite naive or not upto the mark.i have been assigned a task to develop a web app which integrates the twitter pull request with another application using the particular application APIs.basically i dont know what it means.Can anyone explain what is intended to be done and if there is any example of such web apps if any,it will be most appreciated, so that i can get an idea of what is to be actually done.i'm planning to do this using ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:-)

Let's see if I can help in any way here.

There is an existing application. This application does something and is used extensively for that one purpose. Do you know what this application is used for?

The application has an API with which one can interact with it. Interactions with the application may quite likely include - among other things the following:

1. The ability to add new information to it.
2. The ability to delete some existing information in it.
3. The ability to update some existing information in it.
4. The ability to query for some information from it.

You are tasked with writing a web app that integrates twitter pull request with this application.

[pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) is a term associated with Git/Github Version control software, and doesn't really make sense with twitter.

Take a look at this detailed blogpost : [Data mining with Ruby and Twitter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-dataminingrubytwitter/index.html) - could give you a better idea about what twitter integration means, and how ruby can be used to integrate twitter with another application.

Hopefully, all the above should help you in getting more clarity on what needs to be done. Or at least a set of questions to ask the person who gave you the task.

Good luck.

On a slightly unrelated note, I strongly recommend that you go through the online [Rails Tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). It will help in understanding how to build web applications using Ruby on Rails. It will also introduce all the tools required to be used while working with Rails, and the best practices in the Ruby/Rails world.